# iOS7 apps only using iPad only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I would like to develop iOS apps but due to budgetary issues I can only afford an iPad mini gen1 or iPod touch 5th gen. Is it possible for me to make apps for all iPhones and iPads/iPods using just a single device? Another question is how does the latest iOS7 work on ipad mini gen 1/iPod touch and what are the limitations when working with these devices when compared to an iPhone(My target apps are trivia and endless runner games).

Thanks

P.S. I do have a mac with xcode on it and I am developing a cocoa app right now and the question is if i can develop for all io7 devices using just one deceive for final testing.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, If I am not wrong, iOS SDK is just a simulator and not an emulator. I was told that i would need a device running iOS for testing and final deployment.

Comment: You didn't find anything on Apple's dev site?

Comment: Can you develop? yes.  Can you create a that interacts well in the various sized devices with a good interface that makes sense and debug the problems that can arise on a iPhone, or iPad air? Unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. As long as you have a developer certificate and a provisioning profile, you can simulate any device on Xcode runbing any version of iOS. You will also be able to use the iPad mini to test on a device. Bear in mind that iPod touches can't upgrade to iOS 7.
It's also worth noting that when designing multi sized apps spanning retina and standard resolutions, you will have to carefully consider auto layout along with different asset image sizes including rotations

Answer (score 0):

You can develop and do preliminary testing using the simulator for any iOS device.  But you will find some things (e.g., camera) that cannot be tested on the simulator so ultimately you will have to have some kind of access to actual devices for serious testing, or at least have access to someone who does has them.

It is easy enough to email the app to people who are willing to work with the program to test it on various devices.  We started with just the devices we had and have tried to add a more diverse selection as the testing progresses.

I would not be put off by the lack of availability of a particular device for testing; for any real testing, you're going to have have different USERS as well as devices.  Finding users who are willing to commit time to testing a project they may or may not have any interest in is far more difficult than finding a diversity of devices.

Given a choice I'd much prefer having five users test on a single device than one user testing on five devices...